# Closing a Socket with Streams

Tags: java, sockets, garbage-collection

The following question I have is pretty straightforward.

Here is my code:

```
public class Protocol implements Runnable {

    private SSLSocket socket = null;
    private InputStream is = null;
    private OutputStream os = null;

    ...

    public Protocol(Socket s) {
        socket = (SSLSocket)s;
        is = socket.getInputStream();
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        ...
        ping();
        socket.close();
        ...
    }


    public void ping() {

        BufferedWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
            writer.write("OK");
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getLocalizedMessage()); }
        finally { writer = null; }
    }
```

I understand I didn't include a lot of source code, but this should be enough to answer the question. As you can see, in the "ping" method I have a BufferedWriter which I create to write an "OK" string to the remote source. Later on, I close the Socket.

So my simple question is this - From what I understand, since I close the socket, the chain should go like this:

**Close socket ----> which closes is and os ----> closes writer**

So, by closing the Socket, I am also closing and allowing the BufferedWriter to be freed by the GC. Am I understanding this correctly or doing something wrong? Is this true for all writers and readers that I initialize in other methods (i.e. BufferedInputStream). And by setting these variables null at the end of the method, am I helping the GC to distinguish between what should be freed? Or should I not do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). This way, resources are closed automatically and you won't leak them if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @MickMnemonic While try-with-resources was a possibility, this would not be in Android development. So, I wanted to see how this was done without  using the resource statement :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From what I understand, since I close the socket, the chain should go like this:
>
> Close socket ----> which closes is and os ----> closes writer

No. The `BufferedWriter` is wrapped around the socket output stream, but the socket doesn't know that. It has no way of closing it.

> So, by closing the Socket, I am also closing and allowing the BufferedWriter to be freed by the GC.

No and no. The `BufferedWriter` is available for GC as soon as `ping()` returns, and it is never closed at all.

> Am I understanding this correctly

No.

> or doing something wrong?

Yes. You shouldn't create a new `BufferedWriter` per message. You should use the same one for the life of the socket, and close *it* instead of the socket. Similarly you should only use one input stream or Reader for the life of the socket. Otherwise you can lose data in their buffers.

> Is this true for all writers and readers that I initialize in other methods (i.e. BufferedInputStream).

No.

> And by setting these variables null at the end of the method, am I helping the GC to distinguish between what should be freed?

No. You are just wasting time and space. The method is about to exit anyway, so all its local variables disappear.

> Or should I not do this?

You should not do any of it.

Comment: Straight forward and to the point. But closing the Socket does close the Input and Output streams, as stated here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17725358/1593583. So, how come the same effect does not take place with the BufferedWriter since the writer is wrapped around the Output stream? Or is there a difference between saying the writer is "closed" vs "not useable".

Comment: @Zack I didn't say otherwise. Read what I actually wrote. It doesn't *close the `BufferedWriter`.* There is no mechanism. I said so above. The socket has no way of knowing the `BufferedWriter` even exists. It's not *usable*, because the interior stream it is wrapped around is closed, but it isn't closed itself.

Comment: That last sentence of your comment was genius. Thanks for that. Now if I could only figure out why its so important to close the writer rather than the socket, I would be set!

Comment: Because it contains a buffer that may need flushing, as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17736118/207421) in your linked question states.

Comment: For that, you get a +1 in the answer linked and a +1 here. Thanks for the great explanation. I had no idea!